# Disabling 3D touch from opening webviews on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, ios9, 3dtouch

I have a UITextView that displays an NSAttributedString that contains links. When the user taps on a link, my in-app router routes the user to a different part of the app.

I noticed that on iOS 9, with 3d touch, users can now force touch the links which opens up a Safari webview. Often this creates a really bad user experience, or opens up parts of my website, which I don't want on the app.

Is there any way I can disable this?

I'm delegating textView:shouldInteractWithURLinRange: but this method isn't getting called at all for 3d touches...only regular taps.

Answer (score 0):

As of date there is a way. Try it at your own risk: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22295